# How to read contents of ATSAM3X8E chip on Arduino Due Board in Mac OS X

Tags: shell, arduino

I have two [Arduino Due](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) boards with some programming that has since been lost. I need to back up the contents before replacing the program. I’ve been playing around with another Arduino Due before I move to taking the precious program off of the boards in question.

I have [BOSSAC](http://www.shumatech.com/web/products/bossa) running on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion), but am having trouble connecting to the chip and getting the binary file. I’ve tried:

```
bossac -p /dev/cu.usbmodem* -r adlights.bin`
```

But it hasn’t gotten me anywhere. I had read that I need to change the baud rate to `1200`, but using the following command has not done the trick for me:

```
stty -f /dev/cu.usbmodem* 1200
```